# Parisitic inheritance in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Watching a Douglas Crockford lecture on advanced JavaScript and he brings up the idea of parasitic inheritance which is essentially having constructors call other constructors to modify the object in question.  Here is his code:

```
function gizmo(id, secret) {
  secret = secret || {};
  secret.id = id;
  return {
    toString: function () {
      return "gizmo " + secret.id;
    }
  };
}

function hoozit(id) {
  var secret = {},
      that = gizmo(id, secret);
  that.test = function (testid) {
    return testid === secret.id;
  };
  return that;
}

var myHoozit = hoozit(20);
console.log(myHoozit.test(20)); //returns true
```

I understand the code and there is nothing too difficult to grasp here.  The confusion takes place in the `hoozit` function.  If you do not set `secret = {}` you will not get the a `true` being returned.

This is baffling because in the `gizmo` function, you see `secret = secret || {}` which should take care of this for us...  but it doesn't.

Why is that short circuit not working correctly (`secret = secret || {}`) in the `gizmo` function when not being passed a second parameter in the `hoozit` function (breaks in both Chrome and Firefox)??

Comment: How can you test `testid === secret.id` in `hoozit.test` if you don't declare `secret`?

Comment: @Zirak Well, if we changed it to `that.id` I am assuming it would work if the short circuit worked as we thought it would.

Comment: If you didn't have that in in hoozit, it would throw a ReferenceError when invoking gizmo.

Comment: Could you post your altered code, what you think should be working?

Comment: Secrets don't make friends!  Why would you want to have private variables, though?  Someone could easily take that code, modify it to be member variables, and then recreate the class.  The usual rule is to document everything you want to be public, and everything else is undocumented, and shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is that short circuit not working correctly (`secret = secret || {}`) in the `gizmo` function when not being passed a second parameter in the `hoozit` function (breaks in both Chrome and Firefox)??

Simple because you cannot access `secret` inside `that.test` because it does not exist in that scope:

```
function hoozit(id) {
  var that = gizmo(id);
  that.test = function (testid) {
    // secret is not defined in this or in any higher scope
    // hence you get a refernece error
    return testid === secret.id;
  };
  return that;
}
```

The only `secret` object that exists is local to the `gizmo` function.

---

If you define it and just don't pass it to `gizmo`, then `secret = secret || {}` will evaluate to `secret = {}`, i.e. a new object is created inside the `gizmo` function. That value is only accessible within the `gizmo` function and is not related at all to the `secret` variable in the `hoozit` function. The `secret` object inside `gizmo` is a different than the one in `hoozit`.

```
function hoozit(id) {
  var secret = {},      // secret object is created here
      that = gizmo(id);
  that.test = function (testid) {
    // you never set `secret.id`, hence the comparison results in `false`
    return testid === secret.id;
  };
  return that;
}
```

---

There is nothing wrong with `secret = secret || {}`, it is working as expected.

Comment: It's not working for me.  If I take out `secret` in the `hoozit`, it breaks.

Comment: @Sethen: That's what I'm saying and I explained why, didn't I?

Comment: The thing that is confusing me is the `secret = secret || {}` ... This does not seem to be working?  I am calling `gizmo` without anything in the second parameter.  I guess I am just not understanding this.

Comment: I would assume this would work with `that.id` instead of `secret.id`, but it doesn't.

Comment: It *is* working. If `secret` is `undefined`, `secret = secret || {}` is basically `secret = {}`, i.e. it creates a new object inside `gizmo`. That object cannot be accessed from the outside, it is *local* to the function.

Comment: @SethenMaleno, `that` has one property, the `toString` function.

Comment: @Sethen: Here is a simplified example: `var foo = 1; function bar(foo) { foo = 2: } bar(); alert(foo);`. `foo` will still have the value `1` because `foo` inside the function has nothing to do with the variable defined outside of it. That's how variables scope works in JS and that's exactly what happens in your example. `secret = secret || {}` will create a new object (`secret` is not defined) which only exists *inside* `gizmo`. Even if a variable with the same name exists somewhere else, they are not related in any way.

Comment: I understand that, but you're setting `id` in the `gizmo` function when you're calling it inside of `hoozit`.  To me, it would make sense that the `that` variable inside of `hoozit` has the `id` property because `gizmo` sets it with `secret.id = id`.

Comment: @Sethen: `that` is not `secret`, so why should it have an `id` property? `secret` is an object that is referenced by a function that is assigned to an object (`toString` property) returned by `gizmo` (and referenced by `that`). But there is no relation between `that` and `secret`. The function you define in `hoozit` does not have access to the object in created in `gizmo` because they are not in the same scope.

Comment: @FelixKling So what you're saying is that the two `secret` objects have absolutely nothing to do with each other.  These are two separate objects completely.  I guess I thought that `that` held a reference to `secret`.  I guess it does not.  I can see that now because the object created with `hoozit` does not have the `id` property.  So, I am not sure why setting `secret.id` is necessary in `gizmo` then.

Comment: @Sethen: They are different objects if you don't pass the `secret` object from `hoozit` to `gizmo`, yes. *"So, I am not sure why setting secret.id is necessary in gizmo then."* Well, I don't know what the code is supposed to do, so I cannot tell you that. It's a decision someone made.

Comment: So, whats with the `secret.id = id` then?  Couldn't you just use `id` passed instead without the use of an object?

Comment: @Sethen: You probably can, depending on what you want to achieve.

Comment: @FelixKling I got it now.  Thanks.  I changed the code a bit...  It makes more sense to create `secret.id` in `hoozit` and pass it to `gizmo` then the other way around and it works as expected.  Not sure why he was doing it this way, but it seems backwards a bit.

Comment: @SethenMaleno no, you need `secret.id = id`, so `secret.id` exists in the hoozit.test function.

Comment: @vol7ron It exists if I create it in `hoozit` and pass it to `gizmo` as well.

Comment: @SethenMaleno: yes, you're passing `secret` by reference, so the changes to in `gizmo` are reflected in `hoozit`.  But you're using  `secret.id` in `hoozit`, so it has to be set in `gizmo` or `hoozit`.  See my [re-worked example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18037813/183181) for setting it in `hoozit`

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at a simpler example.

```
function Foo(baz){
    baz = baz || {};
    baz.boo = 1;
}

function Bar(baz){
    baz = baz || {};
    Foo(baz);
    return baz;
}
```

If we call `Bar()`, we are passing an object to Foo.  It then aguments the object by setting a `boo` property.  Sweet!

Now, let's say our Bar function looks like this:

```
function Bar(baz){
    baz = baz || {};
    Foo();
    return baz;
}
```

The only difference is that we *are not* passing an object to Foo.  Because of this, Foo is creating an object inside its scope.  We set a property on that new object, and then the function ends.  The object isn't the parent scope of Bar, so Bar never knows this object is created, and has no way of accessing it.  In the next few milliseconds, the object is deleted from RAM because there are no references to it.

---

That's not exactly the case with your question.  The `toString` function references it.  Because the outer scope is complete, it is now a local variable to that `toString` function.  If we didn't pass a `secret` object, then it never leaves that scope.  It must in some way be exported.

The more logical tactic would be to just create it as a property of our original object.  Our secret could easily be accessed by a user that knows what JavaScript is, so we should save some headaches and use a sensible inheritance method.

If you don't know `SomeFunction.call` takes any number of arguments.  The first is whatever you want to be `this` in the function, and the remainder are just the regular arguments.

```
function gizmo() {
    this.toString = function () {
        return "gizmo " + this.id;
    };
};

function hoozit(id) {
    this.id = id;
    gizmo.call(this); // allow gizmo to manipulate this object

    this.test = function (is) {
        return this.id === is;
    };
};

h = new hoozit(1);
console.log(h.test(1)); // true
console.log(h.toString()); // "gizmo 1"
```

Comment: I like the use of `call` here.  Pretty cool, reminds me of inheritance with `Object.create`.

Comment: If you want strict inheritance, you can use `gizmo.apply(this, arguments)`.  Then the arguments for gizmo, are the arguments passed to hoozit, even if gizmo can use more arguments than hoozit cares about.

Answer (score 1):

You need `secret = {}`.

---

It's erroring at `return testid === secret.id;` because `secret` needs to exist.

The main magic you're probably looking for is, where is `secret.id` being populated, since all the operations are happening in `gizmo()`.  The answer is this line: `that = gizmo(id, secret);`

`secret` is passed to gizmo and in JavaScript objects are passed by reference.  This means that if you have a local object and pass that object as an argument to another function, any operations to that object will be reflected locally.

If you didn't want that to occur, you'd need some sort of copy/clone (the term *clone* has been used incorrectly by libraries to suggest a deep copy) of the argument.  But in the example, you do want changes to `secret` in gizmo to update the `secret` in hoozit, so everything is working as it should.

---

Here's another way of writing it:

```
function gizmo(secret) {              // only receive secret, which already has an "id"
   secret = secret || {'id':null};    // if secret not passed create it with a default "id"
   return {
      toString: function () {
         return "gizmo " + secret.id; // the reason why we needed a default "id"
      }
   };
}

function hoozit(id) {
   var secret = {'id':id},            // create a object and set key "id" to hoozit's argument
       that   = gizmo(secret);        // only pass secret

   that.test  = function (testid) {
      return testid === secret.id;
   };

   return that;
}

var myHoozit = hoozit(20);
console.log( myHoozit.test(20) ); //returns true
```